# I have granted users in my Flyway scripts than users changed, now what

Tags: flyway

In my first script, I granted rights to users. Now all users in database has been changed in order to rotate password for the new ones. How do I solve it in my Flyway script if old users don't exist anymore? I mean, those scripts will not be ussable in the new environment, but also, I can't rewrite them because ongoing applications on current environments.
What can I do? Am I suppose to migrate the whole database?